# Powershell - List View Validation

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml

I'm trying to build a script to ease the access mirroring.
I'm comparing access groups of two users and then displaying only those that the second user is missing.

I have two List Views:

- First - Filled in with access groups
- Second - Empty view where I want to copy a group name.

I managed to copy the name from the first to second list view although I'm struggling with creating a validation.

Here's the code I have:

```
Function Add-ItemListView($Item){
 
    if($firstItem -eq $true){
        $userGroupsListView.Items.Add($Item)
        $global:firstItem = $false
    }
    else{
        foreach($i in $userGroupsListView.Items){
            $itemText = $i.Name
 
            if ($itemText -ne $Item){
                $userGroupsListView.Items.Add($Item)
            }
 
        }
    }
}
```

I think it's actually checking if there already exists an item with the same name, but I'm getting an error message:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration may not execute.
```

I will appreciate every direction or tip.

Also is there any documentation for ListView in Powershell?

I could find a bunch of helpful guides and documentation but for C#

Comment: They're objects - you can use `-contains` and `-in` operators. There's no need to iterate through the object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell - Enumerating through a collection and change the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005323/powershell-enumerating-through-a-collection-and-change-the-collection). Copy the collection by using parenthesis: `foreach($i in ($userGroupsListView.Items)){...`